# Setting custom property in config.ini

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want add a property that with a value that is a path to a local directory, for example, `<property name="loc" value="C:\Program Files\myDir" />`.

This works during the build, but when I retrieve this property I get `C:Program FilesmyDir`.

What is the right away to represent file references and URL references in `config.ini`?

Comment: Is this an RCP you are building? What does the config.ini look like in the final build? How are you retrieving the value?

Comment: It's not RCP. Config.ini looks fine except that slashes are not escaped. Values are rertrieved using System.getProperty() method.

Comment: What config.ini are you talking about? How are you specifying this in the build?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say that I have a product file in configuration section of which I define my custom properties.

Comment: But you told me this was not an RCP - a product file is only used in a RCP. Since the RCP config.ini is treated as a Java properties file you need to escape `\\` characters,

Comment: @greg-449 A typo. I meant to say "it's RCP", apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use forward slashes or replace each backslash with two backslashes:

- `C:/Program Files/myDir` or
- `C:\\Program Files\\myDir`

Comment: I've tried fordward slashes, but there was a code that was altering the string that didn't produce expected results.